# Java - Nested Object Data

Tags: java, loops, containers

I work with quite a few REST API's and have come across this scenario a few times and was wondering what the best design approach is for accessing nested data that may be null.

The contrived example below demonstrates an object that contains a map of objects that also contain a map of objects etc. So there is MyClassA which has a map that contains MyClassB objects which contains a map of MyClassC objects which contains a map of MyClassD objects.

To get just the attributes of MyClassD I have to loop through each classes maps check the result is not null before looping through the resulting objects map and repeat, as show in MyClassTests main method below.

For this example I am using a json string to represent the data returned from an API call.  For this reason, I cannot enforce any rules on the maps not adding null values to the map.  Also I am not using the key in the example but this should be taken into account as this is just a contrived example. I am also using the root object deliberately instead of using the ObjectMapper to skip nesting.

MyClassD:

```
public class MyClassD {

    private String dataOfInterestA = null;

    private String dataOfInterestB = null;

    public MyClassD() {

    }

    public MyClassD(String dataOfInterestA, String dataOfInterestB) {
        this.dataOfInterestA = dataOfInterestA;
        this.dataOfInterestB = dataOfInterestB;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dataOfInterestA
     */
    public String getDataOfInterestA() {
        return dataOfInterestA;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataOfInterestA the dataOfInterestA to set
     */
    public void setDataOfInterestA(String dataOfInterestA) {
        this.dataOfInterestA = dataOfInterestA;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dataOfInterestB
     */
    public String getDataOfInterestB() {
        return dataOfInterestB;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataOfInterestB the dataOfInterestB to set
     */
    public void setDataOfInterestB(String dataOfInterestB) {
        this.dataOfInterestB = dataOfInterestB;
    }
}
```

MyClassC:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassC {

    private Map<String, MyClassD> myClassDContainer = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @return the myClassDContainer
     */
    public Map<String, MyClassD> getMyClassDContainer() {
        return myClassDContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param myClassDContainer the myClassDContainer to set
     */
    public void setMyClassDContainer(Map<String, MyClassD> myClassDContainer) {
        this.myClassDContainer = myClassDContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     * @param myClassDContainerValue
     */
    public void addMyClassDContainer(String key, MyClassD myClassDContainerValue) {
        myClassDContainer.put(key, myClassDContainerValue);
    }
}
```

MyClassB:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassB {

    private Map<String, MyClassC> myClassCContainer = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @return the myClassCContainer
     */
    public Map<String, MyClassC> getMyClassCContainer() {
        return myClassCContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param myClassCContainer the myClassCContainer to set
     */
    public void setMyClassCContainer(Map<String, MyClassC> myClassCContainer) {
        this.myClassCContainer = myClassCContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     * @param myClassCContainerValue
     */
    public void addMyClassCContainer(String key, MyClassC myClassCContainerValue) {
        myClassCContainer.put(key, myClassCContainerValue);
    }
}
```

MyClassA:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassA {

    private Map<String, MyClassB> myClassBContainer = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @return the myClassBContainer
     */
    public Map<String, MyClassB> getMyClassBContainer() {
        return myClassBContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param myClassBContainer the myClassBContainer to set
     */
    public void setMyClassBContainer(Map<String, MyClassB> myClassBContainer) {
        this.myClassBContainer = myClassBContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     * @param myClassBContainerValue
     */
    public void addMyClassBContainer(String key, MyClassB myClassBContainerValue) {
        myClassBContainer.put(key, myClassBContainerValue);
    }
}
```

MyClassTests:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MyClassTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClassTests myClassTests = new MyClassTests();
        MyClassA myClassAObject = myClassTests.getMyClassA();
        // Get all the dataOfInterestA and store in list
        List<String> dataOfInterestAList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (myClassAObject != null && myClassAObject.getMyClassBContainer() != null) {
            for (Entry<String, MyClassB> myClassBEntries: myClassAObject.getMyClassBContainer().entrySet()) {
                MyClassB myClassB = myClassBEntries.getValue();
                if (myClassB != null) {
                    for (Entry<String, MyClassC> myClassCEntries: myClassB.getMyClassCContainer().entrySet()) {
                        MyClassC myClassC = myClassCEntries.getValue();
                        if (myClassC != null) {
                            for (Entry<String, MyClassD> myClassDEntries: myClassC.getMyClassDContainer().entrySet()) {
                                MyClassD myClassD = myClassDEntries.getValue();
                                if (myClassD != null && myClassD.getDataOfInterestA() != null) {
                                    dataOfInterestAList.add(myClassD.getDataOfInterestA());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MyClassA getMyClassA() {
        MyClassA myClassAObject = null;
        String json = "{\"myClassBContainer\":{\"MyClassBKey\":{\"myClassCContainer\":{\"MyClassCKey\":{\"myClassDContainer\":{\"MyClassDKey\":{\"dataOfInterestA\":\"Data Of Interest A\",\"dataOfInterestB\":\"Data Of Interest B\"}}}}}}}";
        //      The formatted json from above looks like this:
        /*      {
                    "myClassBContainer": {
                        "MyClassBKey": {
                            "myClassCContainer": {
                                "MyClassCKey": {
                                    "myClassDContainer": {
                                        "MyClassDKey": {
                                            "dataOfInterestA": "Data Of Interest A",
                                            "dataOfInterestB": "Data Of Interest B"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        */
        // Convert the json string to MyClassA object
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            myClassAObject = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClassA.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myClassAObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a design flaw in itself.
I don't know anything about your requirements, but having such a nesting in maps seems weird and in most cases should and could be handled differently.

Additionally the question why an objectMapper cannot be used is there.

Comment: If you need to get "leaf" values, you can do that with Strream.fitrer().map().filter().map()....